# Rx Intersect operator

Tags: system.reactive

I'll start with the simplest to state part of my question is there an implementation of an Rx Intersect operator available out there?

Basically I have two streams which will produce values.
Let's say stream 1 produces: A,B,C,D,E,F,G
And stream 2 produces: B,D,F

Both streams will complete and are not infinite (for background: they are provided by two different data sources which we queried concurrently).

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to implement an asynchronous intersect operator in the Rx world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far as I know, there is no "official" implementation.  Mostly, you would need to collect the values from the two sources to store and check for matches in the opposite source.  Something like this should get you started:

```vb
<Extension()> 
Public Function Intersect(Of T)(first As IObservable(Of T), 
                                second As IObservable(Of T), 
                                comparer As IEqualityComparer(Of T)
                               ) As IObservable(Of T)
    If first Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("first")
    If second Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("second")
    If comparer Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("comparer")

    Return Observable.Create(Of T)(
        Function(obs)
            Dim gate As New Object()
            Dim firstItems As New HashSet(Of T)(comparer)
            Dim secondItems As New HashSet(Of T)(comparer)
            Dim firstCompleted, secondCompleted As Boolean

            Dim disp As New CompositeDisposable(2)
            disp.Add(first.Subscribe(Sub(v)
                                         SyncLock gate
                                             firstItems.Add(v)
                                             If secondItems.Contains(v) Then obs.OnNext(v)
                                         End SyncLock
                                     End Sub,
                                     AddressOf obs.OnError,
                                     Sub()
                                         SyncLock gate
                                             firstCompleted = True
                                             If secondCompleted Then obs.OnCompleted()
                                         End SyncLock
                                     End Sub))
            disp.Add(second.Subscribe(Sub(v)
                                          SyncLock gate
                                              secondItems.Add(v)
                                              If firstItems.Contains(v) Then obs.OnNext(v)
                                          End SyncLock
                                      End Sub,
                                      AddressOf obs.OnError,
                                      Sub()
                                          SyncLock gate
                                              secondCompleted = True
                                              If firstCompleted Then obs.OnCompleted()
                                          End SyncLock
                                      End Sub))
            Return disp
        End Function)
End Function
```

This implementation will repeat matches if the input contains multiple occurrances, but only after it has been found in both sources.  For example

```vb
first  ----1---2---1----2---1---1----|
second ----------2----1-----------|
out    ----------2----1-2---1---1----|
```

If the repetitions are not desirable, you could check to see that it is not in the corresponding source collection.  The subscription to first would change to:

```vb
first.Subscribe(Sub(v)
                    SyncLock gate
                        'check that the first doesn't already contain this value
                        If firstItems.Add(v) AndAlso
                           secondItems.Contains(v) Then obs.OnNext(v)
                    End SyncLock
                End Sub,
                AddressOf obs.OnError,
                Sub()
                    SyncLock gate
                        firstCompleted = True
                        If secondCompleted Then obs.OnCompleted()
                    End SyncLock
                End Sub)
```

with the second subscription changing similarly.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different implementation that works for hot observables, it gives you a set intersection, so if `'c'` appears three times in both streams, it will only appear once in the intersect stream.

```
IObservable<char> stream1;
IObservable<char> stream2;

var intersect = Observable
  .Merge(stream1.Distinct(), stream2.Distinct())
  .GroupBy(c=>c)
  .SelectMany(g=>g.Skip(1).Take(1));
```

Example:

```
stream1    ---a---b--c--d--e--a-b-c
stream2    -b---a---e---------a-b-c
intersect  -----a-b--------e------c
```

Comment: Nice! I thought there might be a way of doing this using grouping. I already marked the answer, but this deserves an upvote.

Comment: How come the last element of `stream2`, i.e. the `c` doesn't get emitted in the `intersect` stream?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do:

```
var intersect = from x in stream1
                from y in stream2
                where x == y
                select x;
```

Comment: That was my immediate thought too, Richard. I figured this would be an easy question to get rep for. I missed out, but I gave you some. :-)

Comment: Two potential problems with this solution come to mind.  What if stream2 is hot and the match from stream1 comes after the matching value in stream2? What if stream2 is cold and making a subscription for each value in stream1 is A Bad Thing(tm)?

Comment: Gideon is correct, if the value from stream1 comes after the value in stream2 it will not match.

Comment: @GideonEngelberth If either of those requirements are needed, then you should only have to use Publish/Delay on the Observables to adjust to your needs.